# Can't make conroller working with params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller

I have has_many association and want get Users Websites and from console user.websites gives me list of all websites, but when I try in controller:

```
     def index
      @websites = User.find(params[:user_id]).websites
    end
```

Gives me error:**EDIT**

```
     Rendered C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (3.0ms)
    Rendered C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.0ms)
   Rendered C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (99.0ms)
         ←[1m←[36mUser Load (2.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` =67 LIMIT 1←[0m
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User without an ID):
 app/controllers/websites_controller.rb:10:in `index'
```

but I am logged in and do have user with id =67:

```
          User.find(67)
         => #<User id: 67, first_name: "admin", ...
```

In my view:

```
 <% @websites.each do |website| %>
 <%= website.name  %>  
   <%= website.url %> 
  <p> <%= website.category %>
  <%= website.language %> 
<%end%>
```

**EDIT.Tried to inspect params[:user_id] in index view, and this didn't show me anyhing:**

```
        <%= params[:user_id]%>
```

Why I'm getting errors ?

Comment: are you sure params[:user_id] is passing to controller?

Comment: show us the full console log, not only 3 last lines

Comment: Mikhail Nikalyukin ,Все ок теперь ?/Is it Ok now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you getting the `params[:user_id]` from?

Have you tried:

```
def index
  @websites = User.find(params[:id]).websites
end
```

You need to explain how you are finding the user.
You said that you are logged in, so do you have a `current_user`?

```
def index
  @websites = current_user.websites
end
```

or do it in parts:

```
def index
  @user = #find the user 
  @websites = @user.websites
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I was doing like this, because it worked in old project.